# Bundle Webpack React library as an ESM module - Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, webpack-5, es6-modules

I need to publish a single package that can be imported as default (or named as last resort) by multiple projects.

After hundreds of issues trying to do this with Rollup I moved on to trying to bundle my library with Webpack. My package only exports one default.

I have another project that is importing the package as default that I have been testing with, it's intended that it should return the root React component which is default exported.

I have tried bundling with UMD, which doesn't crash my external project but doesn't return an exported default or named export anywhere.

If I set my Webpack config to bundle ESM instead I get an obscure vague error regarding Object.defineProperty.

If somebody has ESM bundling working in Webpack 5 please help, or any ideas that have worked for you

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.r (build.js:13594)
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at Object.../discover-v2/dist/index.js (build.js:10623)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:13402)
    at fn (build.js:13671)
    at eval (index.tsx:20)
    at Module../src/views/Discovers/Discover/index.tsx (build.js:5141)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:13402)
    at fn (build.js:13671)
```

This points to a webpack function:

```
/* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
```

webpack.config.ts:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/package.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: {
            // name: 'discover',
            type: 'module',
        },
        libraryTarget: 'module',
        module: true,
    },
    experiments: {
        asset: true,
        outputModule: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        //TODO waiting on https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/issues/61
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        //@ts-ignore
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                exclude: [/node_modules/, nodeModulesPath],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|mov|mp4)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.LOCAL': JSON.stringify(process.env.LOCAL),
            'process.env.STAGING': JSON.stringify(process.env.STAGING),
            'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
            'process.env.NAME': JSON.stringify(pkg.name),
            'process.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(pkg.version),
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            eslint: {
                files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}', // required - same as command `eslint ./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx} --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx`
            },
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/env", { "modules": false }],
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/typescript",
        [
            "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop",
            {
                "autoLabel": "always",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "labelFormat": "[local]"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/transform-runtime",
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Root component - `src/package.tsx`

```
const RootProvider: React.FC<RootProps> = ({ assets, ...props }) => (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <AssetsContext.Provider value={assets}>
                <Root {...props} />
            </AssetsContext.Provider>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </StoreProvider>
);

export default RootProvider;
export { RootProvider as discover };
```

package.json `main/module`

```
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "type": "module",
    ...
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "paths": {
            ...
        },
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declarationDir": ".",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "declaration": true // generates .d.ts files inside the output directory
    },
    "include": ["./src", "./webpack.config.ts", "./webpack.package.config.ts"],
    "exclude": ["dist"]
}
```

Bundle `dist/index.js` output exports (added default and named to test)

```
var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__("./src/package.tsx");
var __webpack_exports__default = __webpack_exports__.default;
var __webpack_exports__discover = __webpack_exports__.discover;
export { __webpack_exports__default as default, __webpack_exports__discover as discover };
```

My consuming project that is importing the package has a similar webpack (without the library config, including aliases to fix multiple react errors when testing packaged project with yarn link), with an exact same .babelrc and tsconfig.json (with path changes)

```
alias: {
                ...
                // bypass multiple react versions issue when testing internal packages
                react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
                'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
                '@emotion/react': path.resolve('./node_modules/@emotion/react'),
                '@material-ui/core': path.resolve('./node_modules/@material-ui/core')
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

From my research, it is related to `eval-*` devtool in webpack config.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11277#issuecomment-724024303

A workaround would be to set it (for the project importing that package) to `false` or change it to something other than `eval-*` according to docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: Good thinking, but I don't use `devtool` in any of my webpack config (as seen in code block above). I got my package working in a build tool called Snowpack instead and it worked like a charm (although dev server doesn't work for me in snowpack, have to use webpack still for this).

Comment: As far as I recall devtool defaults to `eval` in development mode. I've managed to fix my case like that.

Comment: As random as this answer sounds, it was the issue for me. The library used `source-map` while the client app used `eval-cheap-module-source-map`. Switching to `source-map` everywhere did the trick ‍♂️